# Prevent Removing Installed Files if they Have Been Changed NSIS

Tags: installation, nsis, uninstallation

I have a fully functioning NSIS installer and it works great. However, I have just been asked if I could amend the installer so that if any file I install is changed, it is not removed by the uninstaller.

At first glance there is no obvious solution apart from writing the installed file paths to the registry along with their time-stamps, and then checking this information via the uninstall code, removing only the files that have not had their time-stamps updated.

Is there any existing NSIS script/plug-in I can use to do this or anything obvious that I am missing?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would have to store the modified timestamp or file hash (MD5 etc) in the registry or a .ini file during install and compare in the uninstaller...

Comment: Thanks for your time Anders. Do you know of any basic examples of writing to an .ini file that I can look at?

Comment: Just use the WriteIniStr NSIS instruction. If you don't know the number of items it is often smart to write the entries as "1=thename|thedata" so you can enumerate them in the uninstaller...